# Delete from database and run auto increment

Tags: php, mysql

My problem is that I have 10 boxes on the screen. They have an id from 1-10 and when I click delete I run a Ajax to delete the box from the database. So If I delete 5 of them I maybe get id 1,4,5,6,7. Then I create a new one and then want to delete it it has the id 11 because of the auto increment. It jumps over the other numbers. So do you guys have any solutions on this problem?

Can I run a script than starts the auto increment with 1 agian? On the other post this is a bad ide so how to work around the problem?

[image]

Comment: I want the boxes to have id thats is sorted. 1,2,3,4,5,6 ect

Comment: So specify your chosen id on creation

Comment: you can use max(id)+1 instead of auto increment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just ignore the ID, pretend that it does not exist and add another column in the DB ( if it is database ) called something like "order_id" and execute query like

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl
ORDER BY order_id ASC
```

you will get all items in the proper order. When adding new item just set order_id=order_id+1. When deleting an item, remove it and rewrite all "order_id"s to keep them nice.